# Remove line breaks between brackets in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I need to remove line breaks between 「   and   」  after the " 。"

E.g. from this text:

```
「......Sample Text。

Sample Text two。

Sample Text Three」
```

I want to arrive at this:

```
「......Sample Text。Sample Text two。Sample Text Three」
```

Is there any way to do this in Notepad++ regex?

I'm using Japanese version of the windows so 「」are hook brackets in Japanese and 。 is not the English dot(.)

Comment: Do you always have exactly 3 text lines with 2 blank lines in-between?

Comment: Text lines differ in the complete text. They may be 2 or 3 or 4 but there are always 2 blank lines everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer requires using a regex and doing Replace All as many times
as the maximum number of lines that exist inside any one section.

Find what: `「([^」]*?)\R([^「]*?)`
Replace with: `「\1\x20\2`

Where:

- `[^」]*?` : any number of characters that are not `」`, non-greedy match
- `()` : group designation
- `\R` : end of line
- `\1\x20\2` : first group, followed by blank, followed by second group

This is what it looks like:

[image]